# Jquery Login Control in Php

Tags: php, jquery

I have a problem with jQuery. I'm checking the password and username with the code above.
It's working but the issue here is how can I send the data from this HTML form to my PHP file, or how can I start a session here and transfer it to PHP?

```
$("#girisButon").click(function (giris) {
  if ($("#kadi").val() == "" || $("#sifre").val() == "")
    alert('Username or Password is empty');
  else
    $.post($("#login").attr("action"),
      $("#login :input").serializeArray(),
      function (data) {
        if (data == "1") {
          $("#mesaj").removeClass("mesaj").addClass("basarili").text("OK").fadeIn(300);
          // window.location.replace("index.php");
        } else {
          $("#mesaj").removeClass("basarili").addClass("mesaj").text("WRONG").fadeIn(300);
          $("#giris").effect("shake", {
            times: 2
          }, 300);
        }
      });
  $("#login").submit(function () {
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#login").submit(function () {
    window.location = 'phpprocessingpage.php';
  });
```

Then, in phpprocessingpage.php, use POST variables to access any `<input>` elements that were part of the `#login` form:

```
$_POST['input1']
```

I like to save POST variables to my own local variables in this manner:

```
$input1 = (isset($_POST['$input1'])) ? $_POST['$input1'] : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't start a session on javascript and transfer it to PHP. You need to call PHP file on background with necessary parameters and start the session.

According to your script, you are currently making a request to your PHP file using `$.post` method, which takes URL from `#login's action attribute`.

Simply edit the PHP file and create sessions. After that, `echo 1` to browser so javascript can understand your response.

Finally, this is the block that runs if server returns `1`

```
if (data == "1") { }
```

Do whatever you want here. Sessions should be created.